# Remote client can't connect to redisai docker container running in an Azure VM

Tags: azure, docker, networking, redis

I am running two VM's in Azure. One contains the docker container running RedisAI. Accessing that one via the local VM (by ssh-ing into it) works just fine.

The redisai container is run on this VM via the command:

`sudo docker run -p 6379:6379 --gpus all -it --rm redisai/redisai:latest-gpu`

The other VM runs a remote client trying to access the other VM
`redis-cli -h <IP-ADDR>`
which results in
`Could not connect to Redis at <IP-ADDR>:6379: Connection timed out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While typing up the question, I figured out the answer.

I had to allow inbound port 6379 from all sources on both of the VM's in order to a connection to occur over the NSG.

[image: inbound port rule]